# Uploading image to web app with Express and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

My goal is to create a portfolio styled web app to which administrator will be able to upload images for other users to see. I'd like to use Express and MongoDB to achieve that.

My question is what is the best way to do it? I've read some articles recommending storing only file paths in the database, but then how will I be able to host images if I'm using hosting service (file path refer to my local machine, not the one on the server)?

Answer (score 0):

You should had read these :
https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

it's a nice technique for upload file